# How to send an HTTP request for a certain domain name to a specific IP address?

Tags: dns, webserver, http

For testing purposes, is it possible to circumvent DNS and send an HTTP request for a certain domain name to a specific IP address?

For example, let's say you are building a website for `example.com` on server `1.1.1.1`.

Without updating the domain's actual DNS records (e.g. through the registrar or DNS provider) or fiddling with DNS locally (e.g. updating hosts file), how can you test how `1.1.1.1` would respond to an HTTP request for `example.com`?

Comment: Would running a DNS server on your LAN count as fiddling with DNS Locally ?

Comment: This question is totally understandable lol. 2020.

Answer (score 15):

You can use CURL to initiate a request to the server with a custom host header.

```
curl --header "Host:abc.com" xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if you do it by hand its easy.

At a shell prompt: 
`sleep 1; echo GET /some/resource HTTP/1.1; echo host: google.com; echo ''; sleep 10)|tee /dev/tty|telnet 127.0.0.1 80`

This will connect to localhost =127.0.0.1 on the http port = 80 and request `http://google.com/some/resource`

You can do the corresponding in some program of course. The trick is to not rely on the browser or web component to parse the url and use that information to establish a connection.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Google Chrome extension called [DNS Overrider](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dns-overrider/acmhaiiijfheggcaanjlgpampclpbnoh?hl=en) that will allow you to enable a DNS override of a URL on a page. For example, if I had a local html file on my computer that `IFRAME`'d a url (`http://example.com`) then I could use this extension to create an alias that points to `1.1.1.1`.

However, keep in mind that this will not work in your address bar. It will only work on the URLs within a page. Using the `IFRAME` element should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

First, you can issue the request by specifying the IP directly, i.e. `http://192.168.99.99/web/path`.

Second, each HTTP request includes a `Host:` header that tells the HTTP server what domain it wants to reach.  This exists so that multiple domains can live on a single IP.  So if you can find a browser extension or other tool that lets you issue a request and specify that manualy, you can do it.

I haven't used it, but some quick searching turned up a [Modify Headers Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) you can try.

---

You might get SSL certificate errors you need to bypass, if your site is HTTPS and you specify an IP for the URL as it won't have a domain name to compare to the certificate.

Comment: The problem with this is if you're wanting to test your application with subdomains, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*(9 years later)*

When using `curl` you can use at least one of two methods to specify IP address to connect to with given domain name, `--resolve` and `--connect-to`.

> `--resolve <[+]host:port:addr[,addr]...>`
>
> Provide a custom address for a specific host and port pair. Using this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified address and prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to be used. Consider it a sort of `/etc/hosts` alternative provided on the command line. The port number should be the number used for the specific protocol the host is used for. It means you need several entries if you want to provide address for the same host but different ports.
>
> By specifying `'*'` as host you can tell curl to resolve any host and specific port pair to the specified address. Wildcard is resolved last so any `--resolve` with a specific host and port is used first.
>
> The provided address set by this option is used even if `-4`, `--ipv4` or `-6`, `--ipv6` is set to make curl use another IP version.
>
> By  prefixing  the  host  with  a `'+'` you can make the entry time out after curl's default timeout (1 minute). Note that this only makes sense for long running parallel transfers with a lot of files. In such cases, if this option is used curl tries to resolve the host as it normally would once the timeout has expired.
>
> This option can be used many times to add many host names to resolve.
>
> `--resolve` can be used several times in a command line
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> `curl --resolve example.com:443:127.0.0.1 https://example.com`
> ```

> `--connect-to <HOST1:PORT1:HOST2:PORT2>`
>
> For a request to the given `HOST1:PORT1` pair, connect to `HOST2:PORT2` instead.  This option is suitable to direct requests at a specific server, e.g. at a specific cluster node in a cluster of servers. This option is only used to establish the network connection. It does NOT affect the hostname/port that is used for TLS/SSL (e.g. SNI, certificate verification) or for the application protocols. `"HOST1"` and `"PORT1"` may be the empty string, meaning "any host/port". `"HOST2"` and `"PORT2"` may also be the empty string, meaning "use the request's original host/port".
>
> A "host" specified to this option is compared as a string, so it needs to match the name used in request URL. It can be either numerical such as "127.0.0.1" or the full host name such as "example.org".
>
> `--connect-to` can be used several times in a command line
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> curl --connect-to example.com:443:example.net:8443 https://example.com
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Sure you can, you can do this using host files. Depending on what OS you're running you it's done slightly different ways:

**Windows**

*Windows 10, Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows Vista use User Account Control (UAC), so Notepad must be run as Administrator.*

**For Windows 10 and 8**

1. Press the Windows key.
2. Type Notepad in the search field.
3. In the search results, right-click Notepad and select Run as
   administrator.
4. From Notepad, open the following file:
   c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
5. Make the necessary changes to the file.
6. Click File > Save to save your changes.

**For Windows 7 and Vista**

1. Click Start > All Programs > Accessories.
2. Right-click Notepad and select Run as administrator.
3. Click Continue on the Windows needs your permission UAC window.
4. When Notepad opens, click File > Open.
5. In the File name field, type C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts.
6. Click Open.
7. Make the necessary changes to the file.
8. Click File > Save to save your changes.

**Linux**

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Open the hosts file in a text editor (you can use any text editor)
   by typing the following line: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
3. Enter your domain user password.
4. Make the necessary changes to the file.
5. Press Control-x.
6. When asked if you want to save your changes, answer y.

**Mac OS X 10.0 through 10.1.5**

1. Open /Applications/Utilities/NetInfo Manager.
2. To allow editing of the NetInfo database, click the padlock in the
   lower-left corner of the window.
3. Enter your domain user password and click OK.
4. In the second column of the browser view, select the node named
   machines.
5. The third column contains entries for -DHCP-, broadcasthost, and
   localhost. In the third column, select localhost.
6. From the Edit menu, select Duplicate. (The quickest way to create a
   new entry is to duplicate an existing one.)
7. A confirmation alert appears.
8. Click Duplicate.
9. A new entry called localhost copy appears, and its properties are
   shown below the browser view.
10. Double-click the value of the ip_address property and enter the IP
     address of the other computer.
11. Double-click the value of the name property and enter the hostname
     you want for the other computer.
12. Click the serves property and select Delete from the Edit menu.
     From the File menu, select Save.
13. A confirmation alert appears. Click Update this copy.

Repeat steps 6 through 12 for each additional host entry that you want to add.
From the NetInfo Manager menu, select Quit.

**Mac OS X 10.6 through 10.12**

1. Open Applications > Utilities > Terminal.
2. Open the hosts file by typing the following line in the terminal window:
3. sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
4. Type your domain user password when prompted.
5. Edit the hosts file.
6. The file contains some comments (lines starting with the # symbol),
   and some default hostname mappings (for example, 127.0.0.1 – local
   host). Add your new mappings after the default mappings.
7. Save the hosts file by pressing Control+x and answering y.
8. Make your changes take effect by flushing the DNS cache with the
   following command: `dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: The OP specifically asked how to do this **without** fiddling with the `hosts` file.

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1912.html -  http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1033.html

There are workarounds, which I posted. But if you have time and would like to read the RFC you'll quickly learn this isn't possible. If you're interested in taking part in the RFC process you can possibly implement this yourself in the future.

Answer (score -3):

No.

I'm not familiar with that Chrome extension but using IP addresses instead of the the DNS records that resolve to them is not a reliable means of testing website behavior.  For example, the HTTP/1.1 spec introduced the idea of a Host: header, this permitted virtual hosting (multiple sites sharing an IP address, and I would argue a consequent explosion in inexpensive website hosting).  My point is that if you use an IP address rather than a FQDN your browser (with exception to Chrome extension and similar) will not be generating the same headers as it would with a published DNS record, so it's not a real test in the real world.

The "typical" way to do this is exactly what you're trying to avoid: hosts files, "split" DNS, etc.