# How to solve Fastly error: unknown domain

Tags: networking, dns, python

I'm trying to accomplish this task, I have an IP and with the IP I want to make an HTTP request.

Let's say that I have the stackoverflow.com IP (151.101.193.69) and I want to make an HTTP request at the website with python using the `requests` module. I wrtie this code

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://151.101.193.69:80")
response.text
```

that returns the html code of the page.
 Doing so I get a page that says

```
Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.193.69. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

Details: cache-mxp19846-MXP
```

But if I do this with the Google IP it works and the request returns the Google home page

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://216.58.205.174:80")
response.text
```

Comment: Try this in your browser  http://151.101.193.69:80  The result you are getting in python is the same as in the browser  So this is not a python issue, and not a question of how to make an HTTP request. The HTTP request is fine. There's some issue at the server end

Comment: And the question is completely wrong because you know very well how to make a request to an IP since you managed it for google's IP:PORT

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's normal.

HTTP requests always include a "Host:" header indicating what name was actually used in the URL. For example, accessing `http://superuser.com` will send a header `Host: superuser.com`; and if you're using `http://151.101.193.69`, the header will of course show `Host: 151.101.193.69` (or even be completely absent).

The important bit is that many HTTP servers share the same IP address for many different domains (aka [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)), and they *rely* on this header to know which domain you're trying to access.

For example, *all* Stack Exchange domains – `superuser.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, `serverfault.com`, `diy.stackexchange.com`, … – share the exact same set of IP addresses. The only way for the webserver to distinguish between all these websites is by looking at the "Host" HTTP header.

(Additionally, these addresses actually belong to Fastly CDN, not to the real webservers. Large CDNs such as Fastly or CloudFlare might use the same IP address for *hundreds* of domains from various different customers.)

Finally, it is up to the server to decide what it'll do with "Host" headers that it doesn't recognize. Some servers return an error page stating so, other servers return the "first" domain that they have.

---

So in order to make a successful request, you'd need to do this:

```python
requests.get("http://151.101.193.69", headers={"Host": "stackoverflow.com"})
```

But that's a silly way of saying `requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com")`. The only time you might need this method is when you have an IP address that *doesn't* match the DNS information (e.g. if you're trying to [bypass DNS](https://superuser.com/q/719672)).

(And it will cause you more problems as soon as you try to access a HTTPS website, because the domain from the URL is used for checking TLS certificates, too.)

Comment: and if i know only the ip without knowing the host?

Comment: Then you usually cannot access the website, and hopefully the post explains why you cannot. (It might work with dedicated webservers which literally have just that one website, but it usually won't work with webservers which have multiple.)