# Replace server address by IP in wget

Tags: linux, networking, ip, wget, msys2

**EDIT**:
It was suggested this is a duplicate of [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1361680/cant-access-website-by-ip-but-i-can-access-by-fully-qualified-domain).
That is not clear at all for me.

First, the accepted answer suggests 3 possible reasons (which may actually be 2), and one of them was verified by catalin as the cause in *his* case.
It remains to be clarified whether that answers the present case.
[I tried using `--header "Host:us.archive.ubuntu.com"` with `curl`](https://superuser.com/questions/1587335/replace-server-address-by-ip-in-curl), and it doesn't help.
I am not sure this discards the "Host headers" problem as a cause.

Second, catalin means to browse a site. I mean to `wget` from it. I am no expert in networking, but I guess the reasons for catalin's error might be different from mine... even if possibly the same.

I suggest this one is not closed until I can understand and implement the methods to confirm or reject those suggestions.
But it is useful to have those pointers, which I had missed.

---

I mean to use the IP instead of the server name, to directly `wget` a file.
I am under Msys2, Win 10 (that's why post here and not in askubuntu, e.g.), but I guess it would be be the same in Linux.

I couldn't make this work.
I post below the details of what I tried.
I had [a similar failure using `curl`](https://superuser.com/questions/1587335/replace-server-address-by-ip-in-curl).
I wrote a separate post, as I am not sure the explanations and solutions are the same as here.

**What is the correct way of doing this?**

Note: Using `wget ftp://<IP>/...` instead of `wget http://<IP>/...` worked fine.

---

This is what I tried:

1. **Obtain the IP address for the server**.

```
    $ ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
    
    Haciendo ping a us.archive.ubuntu.com [91.189.91.38] con 32 bytes de datos:
    Respuesta desde 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 tiempo=173ms TTL=52
    Respuesta desde 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 tiempo=166ms TTL=52
    Respuesta desde 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 tiempo=172ms TTL=52
    
    Estadísticas de ping para 91.189.91.38:
        Paquetes: enviados = 3, recibidos = 3, perdidos = 0
        (0% perdidos),
    Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
        Mínimo = 166ms, Máximo = 173ms, Media = 170ms
    Control-C
```

2. **Try `wget`ting the file using the server name**.
   **It works ok**.

```
$ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb
--2020-09-21 08:52:23--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.39, 91.189.91.38, 2001:67c:1562::15, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.39|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1637644 (1.6M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb’

yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb.1             100%[======================================================================================>]   1.56M  1.20MB/s    in 1.3s

2020-09-21 08:52:25 (1.20 MB/s) - ‘yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb’ saved [1637644/1637644]
```

3. **Try `wget`ting the file using the IP address**.
   **It does not work**.
   I also tried adding flags `--no-dns-cache` and `--continue`.
   Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243241/wget-command-how-to-download-from-a-specific-ip-address-and-port

```
$ wget http://91.189.91.39/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb
--2020-09-21 09:23:25--  http://91.189.91.39/ubuntu/pool/universe/y/yudit/yudit-common_2.9.6-7_all.deb
Connecting to 91.189.91.39:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Foun
2020-09-21 09:23:25 ERROR 404: Not Foun.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't access website by ip but I can access by fully qualified domain](https://superuser.com/questions/1361680/cant-access-website-by-ip-but-i-can-access-by-fully-qualified-domain)

Comment: Another dupe: [How to send an HTTP request for a certain domain name to a specific IP address?](https://superuser.com/questions/719672/how-to-send-an-http-request-for-a-certain-domain-name-to-a-specific-ip-address)

Comment: @gronostaj - See point 3 [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1587335/replace-server-address-by-ip-in-curl), and EDIT at the top in this OP.
I am not sure I did things right, but at first I wouldn't assume this is a dupe.
That is why I suggest removing the close flags.

Comment: _"Second, catalin means to browse a site. I mean to wget from it."_ - it's the same thing. You make a request for a resource, the server sends the resource.

Comment: It's a duplicate. The issue is the missing `Host:` header in the HTTP protocol. Same as for your other question.